# asp-format attrubute on input tag helper with currency causes an issue on POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1, EF-Core 1.1` app, I'm using ASP.NET MVC Input [Tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) with asp-format attribute as `asp-format="{0:C}"` that correctly displays the currency format on the input tags as `$15,201.45.00`...etc. But when posting the `View` the model still keeps those values in the currency format and hence, as expected, the POST action shown below fails. **Question**: How can we get rid of the currency formatting before posting the model? **Note**: Some examples on Input tag helper [here](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx).

```
public class CustomerOrdersModelView
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int FY { get; set; }

    public float? item1_price { get; set; }
    public float? item2_price { get; set; }
    ...
    public float? item9_price { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<form asp-controller="CustOrders" asp-action="ProductPrices" method="post">
....
<tr>
 <td>Item1:</td>
 <td><input asp-for="item1_price" asp-format="{0:C}" />></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Item2:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item2_price" asp-format="{0:C}" />></td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
     <td>Item9:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item9_price" />></td>
</tr><tr>
     <td>Item1:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item1_price" asp-format="{0:C}" /></td>

</table>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">Update Report</button>
</form>
```

**POST Action:** [that causes the issue]

```
[GetPost]
Public ProductPrices(CustomerOrdersModelView model)
{
  ....
  recToUpdate.item1_price = model.item1_price;
  recToUpdate.item1_price = model.item2_price;
  ....
  recToUpdate.item1_price = model.item9_price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your display you can display the currency symonl near the label. And then display the string in format of {C:2}.

The model should then bind the value correctly.

Comment: What you're suggesting I already know. But I'm exploring the tag helpers. And hence the question is specific to tag helpers. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying ModelBinderAttribute to your model?

For example applying the attribute and then getting the massaged value from the passed in RAW form values

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomerOrdersEntityBinder))]
public class CustomerOrdersModelView
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int FY { get; set; }

    public float? item1_price { get; set; }
    public float? item2_price { get; set; }   
    public float? item9_price { get; set; }

}


public class CustomerOrdersEntityBinder : IModelBinder
{


    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var model = new CustomerOrdersModelView();

        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(CustomerOrdersModelView))
            return TaskCache.CompletedTask;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult =  bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("item1_price");

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
        }

        model.item1_price = float.Parse(valueProviderResult.FirstValue.Replace("$",string.Empty).Replace(",",string.Empty));

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```